# Does such a cache (unreduce) actually exist?

Tags: cpu, cache, algorithm

I'm reading about cache replacement algorithms and one states ([source](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse421/08au/Greedy.pdf), page 37)

> Def. A reduced schedule is a schedule that only inserts an item into
>   the cache in a step in which that item is requested.

What's an unreduced replacement algorithm? Is it when something that's not needed right away is inserted into the cache? Doesn't this actually always happen, as memory is accessed in blocks and a full block (or more) is stored in the cache?

Comment: Probably better suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nifle that's kind of my question, does this even make real sense or is it just some theoretical notion someone dreamed up?

Comment: It's been a long time since I read about this but could you not claim that normal cashing where you insert a block of data without knowing if any of it is going to be used (but you suspect it will because of data-locality) is "*unreduced*"